# How to join two dataFrame where one column having same values(and name) with same size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to just join two dataFrame where one column has same values .

i tried pandas merge function as:

df1.  --> dataframe 1
[data Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFwVC.png)

```
    AU01    subject 
1   0.45      3
2   0.21      3
3   1.45      3
4   0.78      3
```

df2.  --> dataframe 2
[Data Frame 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITaIU.png)

```
      AU02     subject 
1     0.44       3
2     0.34       3
3     1.56       3
4     0.78       3
```

**what i tried :**

```
data = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner" , on="subject")
```

and get the result like this:

[merge result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPsXQ.png)

But i just want to merge the two dataFrame by merging  the common column and keeping other columns as it is.

**My expected output is:**

```
    AU01   AU02   subject 
1   0.45   0.44     3
2   0.21   0.34     3
3   1.45   1.56     3
4   0.78   0.78     3
```

PS: There are other asked question in here but no question help me out.

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: If they have the same values and sizes, why not concat the two frames and drop the dublicate column ?

Comment: @Horbaje i have different  columns name but  one column name is the same for both dataFrame and also have the same data values . Now i have just combine them. what i get you can see in the merge result and dataFrame.

Comment: @MayankPorwal now i edited my question  and wrote the expected output that i wanted .
can you please give me suggestion now ?

Comment: FYI You have a typo on row 4 of df2: `AU2 = 0.78.` The trailing second decimal-place isn't legal in a number, so would force that entire column to be read as string/'object'.

Comment: Assuming column `subject` isn't constant 3 everywhere? Useful if you can edit your example to show another value. Otherwise people might post solutions that only work when `subject == 3` in both dataframes. Anyway, you definitely don't want to merge on `subject` column, it's not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- Check if `subject` of df1 matches `subject` of `df2` **for all rows.**
- If it does, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both `df1` and `df2` on `index`.
- Drop duplicate `subject` column.

Code:

```
In [800]: if df1.subject.isin(df2.subject).all(): 
     ...:     df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('subject_y', 1).rename(columns={'subject_x':'subject'}) 
     ...:

In [801]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[801]: 
   AU01  subject  AU02
1  0.45        3  0.44
2  0.21        3  0.34
3  1.45        3  1.56
4  0.78        3  0.78
```

Comment: its perfectly work for me and thank you so much for your help and one more question how can i do this ignoring the index .            (assume index for all dataFrame is same i.e 0 )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "subject" information is redundant
you can try:

```
df1.combine_first(df2)

   AU01  AU02  subject
1  0.45  0.44        3
2  0.21  0.34        3
3  1.45  1.56        3
4  0.78  0.78        3
```

Comment: Useful to show that the output is what the OP wants, otherwise people are unlikely to upvote this